# Cancel Button in UISearchController Causes SearchBar Glitch

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, user-interface, search

In `viewDidload`, I instantiate the `UISearchController` and add its search bar to the table view's header view, as is standard procedure.

If I tap the search bar and enter some text, results are displayed and I cancel the search here, no problem.

If instead, I select one of the result rows,  push into the next screen, pop back and cancel here, the search bar is glitched.

Here is my searchController:

```
// MARK : SearchController ! //

    var searchController : UISearchController!

    var resultsController = UITableViewController()

    ///////////
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        definesPresentationContext = true
        self.resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.resultsController.tableView.delegate = self
        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController)
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.searchController.searchBar.endEditing(true)
        self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "חפש ברים"
        self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

}
```

## Example of Whole Search bar glitching UI :

[image]

its like the search bar is not the `tableHeaderView` anymore here and its ruining the `tableview` cutting last cell and first cell in half.

## Example of how the tableView looks like regularly :

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When the UI glitches, is the search bar still there if you scroll down? Or has it truly been removed when you tapped Cancel on it?

Comment: The amount of the cell that is cut off looks like the height of the status bar. Are you hiding the status bar anywhere in your app?

Comment: First,the searchBar is still there, Secondly, it cuts off the first and the last cell so it approximately cuts off a whole cell.

Comment: @MikeTaverne I have managed to find a weird but working solution, Take a Look at the answer down below.Thank you for trying to help ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with tremendous amount of settings i have managed to find a solution by myself, I have no idea why these specific settings fix the issue but here is what fixed the issue for me :

## Settings in the attributes inspector:

[image]

## Settings in viewDidLoad :

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
                    super.viewDidLoad()
            
            //MARK : Fixes SearchBar Bugs
        
    self.resultsController.edgesForExtendedLayout = .All
    self.searchController.edgesForExtendedLayout = .All            

self.resultsController.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
                    
// End of Bug Fixes.
```